# how to change wx.BitmapButton back to it's original state wxpython?

Tags: python, bitmap, wxwidgets, wxpython

I am trying to get the current status of the bitmap button in the wx-python.
I have 3 different button states i.e Clicked,  Active, and Disable.
The buttons will be at any of these states in real-time.

I am disabling all the buttons for 5 seconds and after that, I want to retain the states as it shown earlier.
I tired using GetBitmap(), GetBitmapDisabled(), GetBitmapPressed() these function but it didnt work for me.

Let's take an example,
We have button name keypad and it's current state can be active, disable or clicked state depends on the action  [image: Keypad_Active]

Now on press of OK button -> keypad button will change to disable state for 5 second and after that how to revert back to it's original state?

I am facing difficulties in building the logic for this. It would be helpful you can suggest some way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use bitmaps as proxies for the button status. Just store the current status explicitly in your program and update the button accordingly, whenever you change it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did this same, but then buttons are flickring in the app. I used self.SetDoubleBuffered(True) to avoid flicking but that also didnt work. how can I  avoid flickering of buttons?

Comment: @Akshada, you mean you did `button.Enable( true )` and it flickers? Something else is giving you the flickering....

Comment: The button will flicker if you change the bitmap too quickly, but there should be no flicker if you only do it once every 5 second. In any case, this is rather unrelated to your original question, so you should ask a different one about this.